# apche poi parse xls ppt doc java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: apache, search, apache-poi

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/ExcelExtractor, method:  signature: (Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook;)V) Incompatible argument to function
        at DocFileParser.DocFileContentParser(DocFileParser.java:29)

Comment: please provide steps you are doing and code

Comment: Looks like you've compiled your code with one version of Apache POI, and are trying to run it with a very different version. What happens when you ensure you use the same jar everywhere?

Comment: thanks #Gagravarr  your right.. i used two versions of jars classpath and i corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Promoting a comment to an answer - this is caused by you using different and incompatible versions of Apache POI at compile time and run time, normally very different versions to trigger this sort of error!

That could be because you compiled against one and then deployed different jars to runtime, or because you had some older POI jars on your classpath at runtime that took precedence (eg from an application framework)

If you can't spot what incorrect POI jars you are using, you can [use the code in the Apache POI FAQ on the topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) (or any similar code) to check which POI jars are in use at runtime. Ensure you have the same for compiling and running, and you'll be fine!